# ANT_HOME cmd issue in Windows 8

Tags: ant, windows-8, path, cmd

I have set

1. ANT_HOME as C:\Janice\GuideWire\AllSoftwares\apache-ant-1.7.1 (User variables)
   And 
   PATH=%ANT_HOME%\bin (system variables)

It just does not work. I get **ANT_HOME incorrectly set or cannot be located.**

2. I also tried:
   ANT_HOME as C:\Janice\GuideWire\AllSoftwares\apache-ant-1.7.1 (User variables)
   And
   PATH=%ANT_HOME%\bin (User variables)

I tried re starting the system for both the cases. Nothing works. plz help

Answer (score 0):

I have got variables in ***system variables*** section and it's working...

After modification plesae execute:

1. Restart OS
2. Type in command line **set** and check if **ANT_HOME**/**ant** configuration is present
3. Type **ant -v**

Answer (score 0):

If C:\Janice\GuideWire\AllSoftwares\apache-ant-1.7.1\bin is set in the path, then that should work. Make sure this parameter is separated by a semi-colon(;) in path. 
set path=C:\Janice\GuideWire\AllSoftwares\apache-ant-1.7.1\bin;%path%

Or you may try adding double slash once.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to have Java installed and present on path.

Run *cmd* and there:

```
set | findstr ANT
set | findstr JAVA
```

and

```
echo %PATH% | findstr jdk
```

each of those commands need to return something.

Verify your java config by running:

```
java -version
where java
```

result should be as follows

```
c:\Guidewire\TrainingApp\bin>java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)

c:\Guidewire\TrainingApp\bin>where java
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
c:\tools\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\java.exe
```

if it's not, then probably you need to set up Java first

Make sure that your ANT_HOME variable is